# Unable to receive data from python server in an Android emulator client

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

I am trying to write a python (sockets) based server and an Android client, but while
sending data from the server to the client, the client doesn't receive any data. The server receives data from the client.
I think that the problem is possibly with the emulator, and not with the server because I did established a connection and the messages from the server may be blocked by the emulator's firewall. 
Here is the code:

Client:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread Thread1 = null;
    EditText etIP, etPort;
    TextView tvMessages;
    EditText etMessage;
    Button btnSend;
    String SERVER_IP;
    int SERVER_PORT;
    Boolean done = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etIP = findViewById(R.id.etIP);
        etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort);
        tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
        etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        Button btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);

        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                done = false;
                tvMessages.setText("");
                SERVER_IP = etIP.getText().toString().trim();
                SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString().trim());
                Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                Thread1.start();
            }
        });
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    if(! done) {
                        String android_id= Settings.Secure.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        new Thread(new Thread3(android_id)).start();
                        done = true;
                    }
                    new Thread(new Thread3(message)).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private PrintWriter output;
    private BufferedReader input;
    class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvMessages.setText("Connected\n");
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvMessages.append("server: " + message + "\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread3 implements Runnable {
        private String message;
        Thread3(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            output.write(message);
            output.flush();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvMessages.append("client: " + message + "\n");
                    etMessage.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unidirectional behaviour, `client -> server` works, where as `server -> client` does not, is caused by the fact that the emulator is NAT-ed and most likely you have to set a rule to forward the inbound traffic (from a localhost port) to a local port of the emulator.

More info and examples [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).